# Httprequest.Url.Host giving very odd server address

Tags: asp.net

In my Asp.net application I am using `Httprequest.Url.Host` property for getting the sub-domain, but on some requests value of this property is coming very odd like

> l7829765.iavs9x.u.avast.com.

Is it possible that  `Httprequest.Url.Host` value can be manipulated somehow?

Comment: I cleaned your question up some to improve the readability. If you could, please post the code snippet you're working with so we can better answer your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is called load balancing through HTTP redirection.

You're not showing any relevant code, but I guess you're doing a request to some URL, where the response redirects you to a random host to actually handle the request.

You can also see the reverse in action, if you visit http://l7829765.iavs9x.u.avast.com, you're redirected to https://www.avast.com/.

So no, the host value is not "manipulated". Your request actually ends up at another host.